# Does a Priority Queue empty when an object is declared in a scope?

Tags: c++, object, stl, queue

I have declared a priority queue in main, and upon certain conditions being met through if statements, I use emplace to add an object to the queue. Unfortunately upon the if statement exiting, the queue appears to be empty. I checked to see if my queue was not adding the object at all and it appears that while in scope, the object is in the queue. 
I will paste some of the code I'm using here. Sorry if this is a dumb question or i'm using this site wrong, I know how stringent the rules are here, but I've searched for an answer on the site and other places.

```
     int main()
{
int control= 0;

while (control!= -1)
{
int menue_control = 0;
priority_queue<object> neg;
priority_queue<object> pos;
priority_queue<double> test;

cout << "\n pos Empty? " << pos.empty();//1
cout << "\n negEmpty? " << neg.empty();//1
cout << "\n testEmpty? " << test.empty();//1
   //after I run though the if statements once, these return to be empty


std::cout << "\nmenu stuff: Quit\n\n";
std::cin >> menu;
if (menu == 1)
{
    std::cout << "You have selected first Menu option:\n ";
    std::cout << "\nSubmenu:Enter 1 to do OT1 or enter 2 for OT2 ";
    int OT;
    std::cin >> OT;
    string name;
    int num;
    double val;
    if (OT== 1)
    {

        std::cout << "name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout << "Enter number : ";
        std::cin >> num;
        std::cout << "Enter 1 for thing, enter 2 for other thing: ";
        int aaa;
        std::cin >> aaa;
        if (aaa== 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter val:";
            std::cin >> val;
            pos.emplace(name, num, val);
            test.emplace(val);

            cout << "\n posEmpty? " << pos.empty();//0
            cout << "\n neg Empty? " << neg.empty();//1
            cout << "\n test Empty? " << test.empty();//0

            int difference;
            if (!pos.empty() && !neg.empty()) {
                diff= neg.top() - pos.top();
                if (diff> 0)
                {
                    neg.emplace(name, diff, val);
                }
                if (diff< 0)
                    {
                    pos.emplace(name, -1 * diff, val);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "done:\n";
                    }
                }

            }
        if (aaa== 2)
        {

        }


    }
    if (OT== 2)
    {

        std::cout << "Enter name: ";
        std::cin >> name;

        std::cout << "Enter number  ";
        std::cin >> num;
        std::cout << "Enter 1 for thing, enter 2 for other thing: ";
        int aaa;
        std::cin >> aaa;
        if (aaa== 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Etner selling price: ";
            std::cin >> val;
            neg.emplace(name, num, val);
            test.emplace(val);


            cout << "\n pos Empty? " << pos.empty();//1
            cout << "\n neg Empty? " << neg.empty();//0
            cout << "\n tes Empty? " << tes.empty();//0


            if (!pos.empty() && !neg.empty()) {

                int diff = pos.top() - neg.top();
                std::cout << "GOT HERE NOW!";

                if (difference > 0)
                {


                    neg.emplace(name, diff, val);
                }
                if (diff< 0)
                {

                    pos.emplace(name, -1 * diff, val);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "order completely filled:\n";
                }
            }
        }
        if (aaa== 2)
        {
               //do stuff
        }

    }

    }   
//A bunch of if menu statements here that are empty     
    if (menu == 6) { control= -1; }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code (assuming the missing parts) will not have that result. Please post a full compilable, but minimal, example.

Comment: Put together a [mcve] and please, learn to format your code.

Comment: Ok Ill try I'ts pretty long though

Comment: @AleXH "minimal": Remove code that is unrelated until the error does not show up anymore, post the last variant with the error.

Comment: Read the link carefully, twice. The focus is on minimal.  There's no reason the problem you described requires a large amount of code.

Comment: Ok, I posted everything that is necessary. Please assume the class file is working fine including overloaded operators and necessary #include files

Comment: Please don't try to destroy your question now that you have an answer. It may help someone else someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your while loop ends, your priority queue goes out of scope.  At his point you cannot access its value.

I'm surprised that it compiled for you, it wouldn't here. You should compile it with -Wall and get rid of all the errors and warnings.  This would have shown your error.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I checked and you were right, the fix was to move the queues into the main() before the while loop is created. When the while loop went through once, the queue would leave scope. I'm not sure why though and I'm getting no errors. none of the "}" seem to be out of place, perhaps I need some rest. I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: @DisplayName To set warning levels in Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx